# Trouble finding hidden email from a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

Although the webpage doesn't display any email addresses, running my scraper I can fetch that on the console but it comes up cluster documents. Is there any way to keep only email and phone number out of the set of documents? Here is what i am up to:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

def Mainpage():
    url = "https://www.houzz.de/professionals/c/Deutschland"
    response = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    titles = tree.xpath('//div[@class="name-info"]')
    for title in titles:
        Name=title.xpath('.//a/@href')[0]
        FindindEmail(Name)

def FindindEmail(pagelink):
    response = requests.get(pagelink)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    titles = tree.xpath('//div[@class="professional-info-content"]/text()')
    for title in titles:
        print(title.strip())

Mainpage()
```

Here is what is being scraped:
[image]

Comment: They're probably hiding it on purpose from people like you ^^ what do you need it for?

Comment: without the page url it will be hard to help you

Comment: There is no email address on the webpage. There is a link to a webform.

Comment: Hi Arount, Page url is in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution finally:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

def Mainpage():
    url = "https://www.houzz.de/professionals/c/Deutschland"
    response = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    titles = tree.xpath('//div[@class="name-info"]')
    for title in titles:
        Name=title.xpath('.//a/@href')[0]
        FindingEmail(Name)

def FindingEmail(pagelink):
    response = requests.get(pagelink)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    titles = tree.xpath('//div[@class="professional-info-content"]/text()')
    for title in titles:
        if "E-Mail:" in title or "Fax:" in title:
            print(title)

Mainpage()
```